# Reading lines from a different shell using pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm receiving to my main script an argument($1) which is a file I should read the lines of. I then need to do some actions on these lines, and return them "fixed"(actions have been done on them, they're new lines). I do this like that:

```
cat "$1" | isValidParameters
```

`isValidParameters` returns new lines, which I now want to read into an array in my main script. I was thinking of doing something like:

```
while read -r -a arr; do
    :
done < $(cat "$1" | isValidParameters)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. How can I read the lines I receive from `isValidParameters` into an array in my main script so that I can do actions on them there? Thank you.

-----------------------------------------------------
I have edited my code as @chepner suggested:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr+=("$line")
done < <(isValidParameters < "$1")

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

And when I run this, I get no output at all.
What I run is:`./getApartments dos > output.txt`

NOTE: dos is not a real file in my directory, those `isValidParameters` should print: `File is missing`.
Here is `isValidParameters`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:.

if(($# != 1 && $# != 3)); then
    echo "Illegal or missing parameters"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ !(-f $1) ]]; then echo "File is missing";
    exit 1
 fi

#find . $1 \*.flat -print

function search_file() {
    #echo "$1"

    for line in "$1"/*; do 
        if [[ $line == *.flat  && -f "$line" ]]; then
            echo "$line"
         fi

        if [[ $line == *.flat  && -d "$line" ]]; then
            search_file "$line"
        fi
    done
}

while read line; do
    if [[ $line == *.flat  && -f "$line" ]]; then
        echo "$line"
     fi

     if [[ $line == *.flat  && -d "$line" ]]; then
        search_file "$line"
    fi
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read -a` does not read multiple lines into an array; it splits a single line into fields and populates array with those fields. If you are using `bash` 4, you can use the `readArray` command:

```
readArray -t arr < <(isValidParameters < "$1")
```

or append to the array line by line in earlier versions of `bash`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    arr+=("$line")
done < <(isValidParameters < "$1")
```

Comment: what is `<(isValidParameters < "$1")` different from `$(cat "$1" | isValidParameters)` ?

Comment: Because `<` expects a file name, not the contents of a file. `<(...)` provides the name of a "fake" file, from which the output of the enclosed command can be read.

Comment: Editing the question, I will be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: That greatly changes the original question; please start a new one rather than editing this one.